# SQL query to check product_type in WooCommerce

Tags: mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to filter products in WooCommerce by **Simple or Variable Product** through MySQL; but I could not find as how the WooCommerce stores the data and distinguishes between them in database.

I want an MySQL query to list all the Simple and Variable Product; I don't need any PHP code.

Something like:

```
SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = 'product' AND product_type = 'simple';
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

MySQL query to list all **Simple Products**:

```
SELECT
    posts.ID,
    posts.post_title,
    posts.post_author,
    posts.post_date,
    posts.post_date_gmt,
    posts.post_content,
    posts.post_excerpt,
    posts.post_status,
    posts.comment_status,
    posts.ping_status,
    posts.post_password,
    posts.post_name,
    posts.to_ping,
    posts.pinged,
    posts.post_modified,
    posts.post_modified_gmt,
    posts.post_content_filtered,
    posts.post_parent,
    posts.guid,
    posts.menu_order,
    posts.post_type,
    posts.post_mime_type,
    posts.comment_count
FROM
    wp_posts AS posts
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships AS term_relationships ON posts.ID = term_relationships.object_id
INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy AS term_taxonomy ON term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id
INNER JOIN wp_terms AS terms ON term_taxonomy.term_id = terms.term_id
WHERE
    term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'product_type'
AND terms.slug = 'simple'
AND posts.post_type = 'product';
```

Just replace `simple` from `AND terms.slug = 'simple'` line with `variable` to get all **Variable Products**;

*I have tested this SQL query and it is displaying the correct result.*

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much.

Comment: @user1375291: if this helps you then please accept my answer my clicking on to a right tick, and upvote by clicking on the up arrow.

Comment: Super helpful - TY .. @user1375291 you should upvote