# Show lowest simple product price in category page

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce, categories

I want to display the lowest **simple product** price in the `content-oroduct_cat.php` page. The following code from [Fancy Squares](http://fancysquares.com/woocommerce-get-lowest-price-category-archive-archive-product-php/) works for showing the lowest price but I want to show **Simple products** only, i.e. omit grouped products.

```
/* SHOW LOWEST PRICE ON CATEGORY PAGE */
//woocommerce get lowest price in category
function wpq_get_min_price_per_product_cat($term_id)
{    
    global $wpdb;

    $sql = "
    SELECT  MIN( meta_value+0 ) as minprice
    FROM {$wpdb->posts} 
    INNER JOIN {$wpdb->term_relationships} ON ({$wpdb->posts}.ID = {$wpdb->term_relationships}.object_id)
    INNER JOIN {$wpdb->postmeta} ON ({$wpdb->posts}.ID = {$wpdb->postmeta}.post_id) 
    WHERE  
      ( {$wpdb->term_relationships}.term_taxonomy_id IN (%d) ) 
    AND {$wpdb->posts}.post_type = 'product'  
    AND {$wpdb->posts}.post_status = 'publish' 
    AND {$wpdb->postmeta}.meta_key = '_price'
    ";

    return $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare($sql, $term_id));
}
```

I tried using :

```
AND {$wpdb->posts}.product_type = 'simple'
```

but this didn't work. How would I display only simple products?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You query is not working because `product_type` is not stored in
>   `posts` table it is stored in `term_taxonomy` table. To get the
>   desired you have to use Sub query, which will fetch all the simple
>   product and the main query filter it according to category.

I have modified your `wpq_get_min_price_per_product_cat()` as below

```
function wh_get_min_price_per_product_cat($term_id)
{
    global $wpdb;

    $sql = "
    SELECT  MIN( meta_value+0 ) as minprice
    FROM {$wpdb->posts} 
    INNER JOIN {$wpdb->term_relationships} ON ({$wpdb->posts}.ID = {$wpdb->term_relationships}.object_id)
    INNER JOIN {$wpdb->postmeta} ON ({$wpdb->posts}.ID = {$wpdb->postmeta}.post_id) 
    WHERE  
      ( {$wpdb->term_relationships}.term_taxonomy_id IN (%d) ) 
        AND {$wpdb->posts}.post_type = 'product' 
        AND {$wpdb->posts}.post_status = 'publish' 
        AND {$wpdb->postmeta}.meta_key = '_price'
        AND {$wpdb->posts}.ID IN (SELECT posts.ID
                FROM {$wpdb->posts} AS posts
                INNER JOIN {$wpdb->term_relationships} AS term_relationships ON posts.ID = term_relationships.object_id
                INNER JOIN {$wpdb->term_taxonomy} AS term_taxonomy ON term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id
                INNER JOIN {$wpdb->terms} AS terms ON term_taxonomy.term_id = terms.term_id
                WHERE term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'product_type'
                AND terms.slug = 'simple'
                AND posts.post_type = 'product')";
    return $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare($sql, $term_id));
}
```

*Code goes in [`functions.php`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Functions_File_Explained) file of your active child theme (or theme). Or also in any plugin php files.*

**USAGE**

```
echo wh_get_min_price_per_product_cat($cat_id);
```

**Code is tested and works.**

Reference: [SQL query to check product_type in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41254608/5019802)

Hope this helps!