# woocommerce variable products database structure

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm building a wordpress eshop using woocommerce and I want to integrate it with an existing erp tool. I have complete the 90% of all the connections but I'm facing a problem with variable products and I can't find a solution by reading the documentation.  I need some more info about how to create a variable product through the erp.

Below is what I'm currently doing:

I am creating an entry in wp_posts with post_type product and for the variation and I'm creating another entry on wp_posts with post_type product_variation and post_parent the ID of the product that holds the variation.

I believe that I'm missing something because doing only the above is not working as expected.

Comment: What problem are you facing?

Comment: _i'm missing something_ Yes you are missing **many thing**, first of all there are various EXTRA meta fields that needs to be added in main product `postmeta` table, and also you have to [add `taxonomy`, `term` for main product](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41254608/5019802). Moreover you also have to add postmeta table with attribute name and value for which it is variable. _I'm flagging this question as too broad because it will take atleast 2 page to explain the whole logic_

Answer (score 2):

I will write what I am using.

```
update wp_postmeta set meta_value = 270 where post_id in (
    select id from wp_posts where post_parent = 46 and post_type = 'product_variation'
) and meta_key = '_regular_price';
```

... where 270 is my new price for all variable products.

... using select to test the solution:

```
select * from wp_postmeta where post_id in (
    select id from wp_posts where post_parent = 46 and post_type = 'product_variation'
) and (meta_key = '_regular_price' or meta_key = '_sale_price');
```

You can see all meta_key related to the wp_posts with:

```
select distinct meta_key from wp_postmeta where post_id = XX;
```

In my case, the 46 is the post_id. For you see what is your, open the product in wp-admin.

I hope that I was helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be getting the types wrong. Variations are of the `post_type` "product_variation" not "product".

Also make sure you have the appropriate `wp_postmeta` values. For example if you have a product variation that has no price it will actually not work during checkout even if it's a free product.

To see what `wp_postmeta` values you need, simply search that table for a product id that you got from a product that you created through the WC back-end.